# HTML/CSS images alignment

Tags: css, html

I have this code:

```
<div id="mainDiv" style="text-align:center>
<img src="redFarm.jpg" style="width: 250px">
<img src="board.jpg" style="width: 750px">
<img src="blueFarm.jpg" style="width: 250px">
</div>
```

The board image is exactly at the center of the screen. Now, the other one are aligned to the as more to center as possible, and I want them to be as more to the borders (left and right) as possible. I have tried many combinations but no luck with any of them. 
Can you guys give me a pointer?

Thanks

Comment: Do you fancy posting your CSS/JS?

Comment: I don't see how this relates to JavaScript or HTML5.

Comment: Use this one 0x28ff44;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try floating the images left and right:

```
<div id="mainDiv" style="text-align:center">
<img src="redFarm.jpg" style="float:left; width: 250px">
<img src="board.jpg" style="width: 750px">
<img src="blueFarm.jpg" style="float: right; width: 250px">
</div>
```

This puts the images at the top of the container; if this is a problem you can try specifying the height explicitly.

Comment: I've tried that already and it didn't worked. The image stays in the same place

Comment: It works fine for me (in Chrome). What browser are you using?

Comment: It must be something from behind because I tried just this code and it also worked